# Inequality involving $\log \cosh$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Show that for $y>x\ge 0$ :

$$\bigg(\frac{y^2-x^2}{\cosh^2(x)}-x\tanh(x)-y\tanh(y)\!\bigg)\log\!\bigg(\frac{\cosh(y)}{\cosh(x)}\bigg) + \tanh^2(x)\big(y^2-x^2\big) > 0 $$

The function $\log(\cosh(x))$ is convex, and $\log(\cosh(\!\sqrt{x}))$ is concave on $[0,\infty)$, but neither of the corresponding inequalities work.

This inequality is important to prove uniqueness of stable optima in the unmixing and deconvolution of linear mixtures of independent random variables with strongly sub- and super-gaussian densities, using the variation diminishing property of densities with monotone likelihood ratio. This inequality is essentially $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\,\log f(x,y)<0$ for the relevant density function.

Edit with possible progress: Using the bound:

$$\log(\cosh(y))-\log(\cosh(x)) \ge \sqrt{y^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+1}$$

with just the positive $(y^2-x^2)/\cosh^2(x)$ term, we can isolate the $\log \cosh$ term, producing the following inequality. For $y>x\ge 0$:

$$\frac{\big(\sqrt{y^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sinh^2(x)\big)\big(y^2-x^2\big)}{\cosh^2(x)\big(x\tanh(x)+y\tanh(y)\big)} - \log\!\bigg(\frac{\cosh(y)}{\cosh(x)}\bigg) \;>\; 0$$

This function is increasing in $y$, taking the derivative with respect to $y$ would eliminate $\log \cosh$, and it would suffice to show that this expression is positive. However the derivative expression is complicated and seemingly more difficult to prove non-negative.

Comment: If I had to work on this, I would let $y=x+z$ with $z > 0$ and see what happens.

Comment: Did that. As well as $y = \sqrt{x^2+z^2}$.

Comment: @japalmer You should mention any attempts you tried in the OP. That way 1) you won't get redundant suggestions of something you have already tried that did not work and 2) someone might be able to salvage an attempt or suggest related methods.

Comment: @NapD.Lover I don't think setting $y=x+t$ really merits mentioning as an "attempt". Any productive work I had done I would have mentioned. But thanks for your condescending comment. Did you downvote this post?

Comment: @japalmer I had no intention of condescending you and I actually upvoted your reply to marty. The question is definitely interesting. My apologies.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Oh ok, sorry. Someone downvoted it. I don't understand why people do that.

Comment: There is a lower bound for $\log\cosh(y) - \log\cosh(x)$ but it's the wrong direction. There is an upper bound based on concavity in $\sqrt{x}$, but it's not tight enough. It took a lot of work to get it to this point. But nothing I have tried to prove this inequality has yielded anything helpful.

Comment: There is apparently no solution for the zeros of the $\log \cosh$ multiplier.

Comment: Anyone have a suggestion on a possibly involved technical approach to proving this inequality? Are there examples of inequalities like this that don't have a known proof?

Answer (score 2):

At least, if $y=x+\epsilon$, the expression is
$$\frac{1}{12} \text{sech}^4(x) (10 x \cosh (2
   x)-4 x-3 \sinh (2 x))\,\epsilon^3+ O(\epsilon^4)$$ and the term in parentheses is positive

$$10 x \cosh (2
   x)-4 x-3 \sinh (2 x)=16 x^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^n (5 n+6) }{\Gamma (2 n+4)}\, x^{2 n}$$

Comment: This only works for $\epsilon \to 0$, right?

Comment: @japalmer. Yes, for sure ! This is why I used $\epsilon$